# Normalization in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

I have a document structured like this

ITEM:

```
objectID
itemDesc
categoryID
categoryName
subCategoryID
subCategoryName,
price
flavor
itemDesc
...
```

Though generally MongoDB does not encourage normalization, I am concerned if there would be data integrity issues if I don't normalize this.
I expects hundreds of thousands of records (possibly millions) in this application.

Is this schema a better option?

CATEGORY:

```
categoryID
categoryName
```

SUBCATEGORY:

```
subCategoryID
subCategoryName,
```

ITEM:

```
objectID
itemDesc
categoryID
subCategoryID
price
flavor
itemDesc
```

Comment: This is too broad IMHO. A *lot* has been written here about schema design, and a thorough discussion of schema design requires much more knowledge of the queries, the problem domain and the cardinality of collections than what you posted.

Comment: I would be querying things like - select distinct category; select distinct subCategory where category = $, select * from item where category = ? & subCategory = ?;
As regards to cardinality, I expect data like 20 categories, with 50 sub categories to have 100,000 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how the end-user will interact with your application.

From what you have commented up until now, I understand that your queries will most likely fall into one of the below categories:

- Bring all items from category X
- Bring all items from subcategory X
- Bring all items that are part of the X category and Y subcategory

If that is the case, I think that it would be best if you use just use one collection to store your data, as your structure is not that complex and there are no complex many-to-many relationships.

As stated in the official [MongoDB Data Model Design](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/) documentation:

> In general, use normalized data models:
>
> when embedding would result in duplication of data but would not
> provide sufficient read performance advantages to outweigh the
> implications of the duplication.
>
> to represent more complex many-to-many relationships.
>
> to model large hierarchical data sets.

Regarding performance, I think that it is better to create indexes that fit your query pattern and fetch data from one collection instead of having to query multiple collections.